# Laravel 4 - Class resolution not working

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I have a controller:

```
<?php namespace controllers;

class XController extends \BaseController {
    public function loadHome() {
        $view = new \views\XView;
        $html = $view->Build();
        return $html;
    }
}
```

And a View

```
<?php namespace views;

class XView{

    public function Build()
    {
        return "oi oi";
    }
}
?>
```

Also, I've added this line in my classloader in my global.php

```
app_path().'/views',
```

and have tried

```
composer dump-autoload
```

It just keeps giving me

```
Class 'views\XView' not found
```

Any ideas?

P.S. I'm intentionally not using Blade.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Composer won't help if you don't use composer.json. So, edit your composer.json and add your views folder to it:

```
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        ...
        "views"
    ],
},
```

Then you do

```
 composer dump-autoload
```

And check the file

```
vendor/composer/autoload_classmap.php
```

Your classes must appear there, otherwise it won't work.

Comment: Thank you, that did it.
Could you also pls tell me what composer dump-autoload does? If I'm having to add the file manually to the composer.json anyway, what purpose does it serve?

Comment: Are you adding the file or the directory? `composer dump-autoload` scans all configurated folders searching for classes, to create the autoloading files. That's why they appear in the autoload_classmap.php. Laravel uses the `vendor/autoload.php`, which helps PHP finding the class files your application needs. Otherwise you would have to `require` all those class files.

Comment: Ok, thanks for that - I've had a snoop around vendor/*

Political correctness aside, what do you personally think about this composer business? It seems awfully overkill. I would typically only have to require 2-3 files per controller/model/view if I've got loosely coupled code so why this hassle.